# put django template tag in static file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want to put some template tag for configuration in js static file, and it will get included by  in html file. How do I pre-compile the file ? is there any way like ruby
's js.erb file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have some javascript file the source dir is different based on different environment

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing stops you to just do that, maybe like this:

`page.html` template:

```
<script>
    {% include "settings.js" %}
</script>
```

`settings.js` template:

```
var SETTINGS = {
    'MEDIA_URL': '{% get_media_url_example %}',
    ...
};
```

If you don't want an inline JS code, but a separate file, you can use [Django Compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which can generate compressed static files from inline JavaScript. Example usage from documentation:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress js %}
    <script src="/static/js/one.js"></script>
    <script>obj.value = "value";</script>
{% endcompress %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render anything:

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("My name is {{ person.first_name }}.")
>>> d = {"person": {"first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Johnson"}}
>>> t.render(Context(d))
"My name is Joe."
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context